# British National Grid Shapefile - convert to WGS84 Lat/Lon

Tags: mapping, coordinate-systems, wgs84

I have a set of ESRI shapefiles which, I'm told, have been written using the British National Grid coordinate system. I need to convert these files to WGS84 lat/lons, for onward conversion to KML files. I'm having trouble doing this as follows:

If I open each of the original files in MapInfo Professional telling it that my file has a projection which is British National Grid then I can't see any geographic objects in the file; the map window is completely empty.

If I use MapInfo Professional's Universal Translator to convert the files to a WGS84 MapInfo TAB file then, just as before, the converted file won't display any geographic objects, the MapInfo window is empty.

Can I verify the coordinate system of these files? Am I missing anything here? Should I be able to convert the shapefiles in the way I'm expecting to be able to and view them using MapInfo Professional? Will another tool do a better job for me?

Thanks.

More Info:

My shapefile has coordinates which don't seem to translate to lat/lon properly and I'm now wondering if the coordinates aren't actually British National Grid. I'm seeing coordinates such as 383702523, 399081141 which appears to be approximately lat/lon 53.488182, -2.247153. Have you any idea what projection system my input file is in?

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I eventually did write my own code to solve the conversion and so am able to deliver the converted data. I'm still keen to know if OGR2OGR or another tool could have done the work without me coding a solution and so welcome further comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

OS grid doesn't use WGS84 - it uses Airy 1936  (OSGB36) spheroid
So you need to go from OSgrid -> lat/lon then OSGB36->WGS84.

See http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/docs/convertingcoordinatesEN.pdf

To do OS grid to lat-lon see http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html

Then to go from OSGB36 -> WGS84 see http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-convert-coords.html

Answer (score 3):

http://gothos.info/2009/04/14/transform-projections-with-gdal-ogr/

ogr2ogr is a great tool for doing these sorts of conversions. You would run it with a command like

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 map_wgs84.shp map_original.shp
```

-t_srs is the option to transform co-ordinate systems. 4326 is the EPSG SRID for WGS84.

Comment: Thanks for this. It pointed me in the right direction but I'm still having trouble.

My shapefile has coordinates which don't seem to translate to lat/lon properly and I'm now wondering if the coordinates aren't actually British National Grid. I'm seeing coordinates such as 383702523, 399081141 which appears to be approximately lat/lon 53.488182, -2.247153.

Have you any idea what projection system my input file is in?

Thanks.